# Login vTigerCRM via User Name & Password

Tags: sugarcrm, vtigercrm

According to the [REST API documentation of vTigerCRM](http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html), its [API](http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html) only supports login with user name & access key.

Since vTigerCRM is based on SugarCRM, and API of SugarCRM allows user name & password to login, is there any chance that vTigerCRM can also login with user name & password?

*Using vTigerCRM version 6.4.0*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use username and access key. If you change the password of that user then also your code will work (i.e. you dont have to change the password in the code as you are using access key).